# How to maintain PHP session when switching the user to a different server

Tags: php, session

I need my users to be able to easily switch between all their accounts after they've authenticated on one of their accounts.

I do this by simply setting the new accountid into session and reloading the page (when they click on a different account name).  It works perfectly fine as long as all their accounts are on the same server, but if the account they're switching to is on a different server then the session is obviously lost, and the system doesn't know they're authenticated and they're redirected to the login page.

Is there a way to transfer a session object when I redirect the user to the other server?

And no, storing the session in a central database is not an option because each server has its own database for performance reasons.

Comment: any reason why you dont have a shared persistence (db, memcache, etc ?) and use that for your session handler ?

Comment: I used to keep session in the db but it was a performance hog.  I'm not familiar with memcache.

Answer (score 0):

You must resolve 2 problems:

1. Must pass session_id to new server, eg. by: passing it in URL or configure [session cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to be accessible on all servers
2. You must store session  in a way, that allows read data on all servers. Eg.: Store in database (small site) or `memcached`

Comment: I am using session cookie to maintain session across all subdomains but I don't see how that would help across servers.   session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.timesavr.net');  Coincidentally the two servers are using the same domain just different subdomains.

Comment: You're the second person to suggest memcache.  Perhaps it's time I start researching that.  Thanks!

Comment: 1. Not `memcache`. `memcacheD`. Many people don't see difference. http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php

Comment: I don't understand how memcached can "share" the session across two servers when it has to be installed separately on each server.  Isn't the session stored in the memory of the server I'm on?  How then can the other server read this same memory?

Comment: I don't know how to answer you to such simple question... If you run memcached server on external interface (real server IP) you can connect to it from anywhere

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for.  What's obvious to you may not be obvious to everyone else.  Thanks!